# Zero pad all columns of different length in a file using shell script

Tags: database, shell, sh

I have to load data into informix Database using a load file which is "|" delimited.

The schema of table is :
Column A: char(9)
Column B : char (6)
Column C: char(3)
Column D: char(8).
My loaded file has data which is not in the same format as required to be inserted in database.

Since data is too huge I don't want to rely on excel. If I cut each column in file and then use `printf("%09d" col1, "%06d" col2)` and so on then it takes longer time.

Can anyone suggest for using better shell commands.

Answer (score 4):

Let's take this as a sample data file that we want to reformat:

```
$ cat data
1|2|3|4
5|6|7|8
```

Using awk, we can create the `|`-separated 9-wide, 6-wide, 3-wide, and 8-wide format:

```
$ awk -F\| '{printf "%09d|%06d|%03d|%08d\n",$1,$2,$3,$4}' data
000000001|000002|003|00000004
000000005|000006|007|00000008
```

awk is generally quite fast and efficient.

#### How it works

Awk implicitly processes every line in the supplied files, one line at a time.

- `-F\|`

  This tells awk to use `|` as the field separator.  We have to escape `|` because it is a shell-active character.
- `printf "%09d|%06d|%03d|%08d\n",$1,$2,$3,$4`

  Similar to `printf` in other languages, this prints out the four columns in the specified formats.

Comment: Thanks :) will try this